# In multilingual site, how to ignore region for sc_lang param in jss layout api and get the appropriate language content

Tags: jss, multilingual

By default, to get a specific language content, we need to pass the query `params` for `sc_lang` as `es-MX`, `fr-FR`..ETC (`sc_lang="es-MX"`) in the JSS layout API to get the specific lang contents.

Is there any way to ignore the region and only send the language like `sc_lang="es"`

```
https://scdev9.3cm.dev.local/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item={8AFD4EBE-1072-4E86-8C33-7F7C8780C36A}&**sc_lang=es**&sc_apikey={03FCC368-DDA2-4B5F-95AB-5DCF35245E16}
```

Answer (score 2):

**This is not JSS specific but we used this approach in a JSS project.**

To ignore the region on the item language version, we changed the language item name and the values of specific fields like Regional Iso Code in the master DB. But then we also had to migrate all the items language field.

This change caused some problems with resolving for example the `Display Name` or `Title` field, because the language of the field template has to be with region (that's how Sitecore works, there is no option to change this behavior in the language settings). But the solution for that was to only create the field template in the specific language with region.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a specific language and set the fallback language value without the region name. and It will work and fallback to **es**. please check the screenshot of the Arabic language we have created.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the options with almost minimal effort could be to use Language fallback module where if you set it correctly it will give you back values fallbacking to general language code.

For example you will create content in "es" language. You could chain language fallbacks also so for "es" language, "en" would be fallback. For "es-MX" language, fallback language would be "es".

This would be your chain "es-MX" -> "es" -> "en".

When you ask for es-MX it will fallback to "es" if content not present and it will fallback to "en" if there is even no "es" content.

Therefore you don't need to change anything in JSS, all is needed is to setup language fallback